# jQuery mouseenter + mouseleave + click to change separate class / styling of 3 <li>

Tags: jquery, html-lists, addclass, mouseleave, mouseenter

I have a set of 3 `<li>` that I need to change the class of each on **mouseenter**, **mouseleave** and **click**.

So far everything is working except when I click, the 3rd `<li>` doesn't stay in the **mouseenter** state. It disappears.

[click here to see how it works so far](http://www.fixxed.net/test/let/let-films-film.htm)

CODE:

```
$(function(){
    $(".hidden").hide();
$(function(){
    $("#list ul li").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).parent().children().first().addClass('name');
        $(this).parent().children().next().addClass('title');
        $(this).parent().children().last().show().addClass('award');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).parent().children().first().removeClass('name');
        $(this).parent().children().next().removeClass('title');
        $(".hidden").hide();               
    }).click(function(e){
        $('.perm-name').removeClass('perm-name');
        $('.perm-title').removeClass('perm-title');
        $('.perm-award').removeClass('perm-award');
        $(this).parent().children().first().addClass('perm-name');
        $(this).parent().children().next().addClass('perm-title');
        $(this).parent().children().last().show().addClass('perm-award');

    }); 
    $("#list ul li").first().trigger('mouseenter');

});
```

CSS:

```
.name,.perm-name { color:#454444; }
.title,.perm-title { color:#930303; }
.award,.perm-award { color:#454444; font-size:11px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="list">

          <ul>
            <li>THE KILLERS.</li>
            <li>WHEN WE WERE YOUNG</li>
            <li class="hidden">(2006 Grammy Nominated, Best Long Form Video of the Year)</li>
      </ul>                
        <ul>       
            <li>COMMON.</li>
            <li>TESTIFY</li>
            <li class="hidden">(2005 Music Award Nominated, Director of the Year)</li></
        </ul>         
      <ul>
            <li>DURAN DURAN.</li>
            <li>FALLING DOWN extended version</li>
            <li class="hidden">(2008 Music Award Nominated, Video of the Year)></li>
        </ul>            
        <ul>
            <li>ARTFUL DODGER.</li>
            <li>short film</li>
            <li class="hidden">(2004 Music Award Nominated, Director of the Year)></li>
        </ul>

 </div>
```

Comment: `.parent().children()` -> `.siblings()`.

Comment: Also, you should think about using `.end()` then `.first()`, `.next()`, `.last()`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a full HTML page with the functionality you're looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #999;
        }

        ul li a:hover,
        ul li a.selected {
            color: #454444;
        }

        ul li a:hover > span,
        ul li a.selected > span {
            color: #930303;
        }

        ul li a > span.hidden {
            display: none;
            font-size: 11px;
            color: #999;
        }

        ul li a:hover > span.hidden,
        ul li a.selected > span.hidden {
            display: inline;
        }
        </style>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("ul li a").click(function() {
                $("ul li a").removeClass("selected");
                $(this).addClass("selected");
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    THE KILLERS.
                    <span>When We Were Young</span>
                    <span class="hidden">(2006 Grammy Nominated, Best Long Form Video of the Year)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    COMMON.
                    <span>Testify</span>
                    <span class="hidden">(2005 Music Award Nominated, Director of the Year)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    DURAN DURAN.
                    <span>FALLING DOWN extended version</span>
                    <span class="hidden">(2008 Music Award Nominated, Video of the Year)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    ARTFUL DODGER.
                    <span>short film</span>
                    <span class="hidden">(2004 Music Award Nominated, Director of the Year)</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

You're not looking for much jQuery - you should take a look at some books on HTML and CSS before continuing your work, it'll save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: Alec, is there any reason you can think of as to why this wouldn't work on the iPad only after I add class="selected" to the first <li>?  I need the first <li> to show selected. Works on every browser but iDevices.

Comment: Assuming you haven't changed the CSS at all... the CSS I wrote takes the "selected" class on the links (so on the `<a>` element).  If you'd rather have it on the `<li>` element there are some quick CSS and jQuery modifications you'd have to make first.

Answer (score 0):

why do you have one document.ready inside another one

```
$(function(){
    $(".hidden").hide();
$(function(){

    });
});
```

if you want to add two document.ready functions in page .

you should do it like this

```
$(function(){
   //your code
});

$(function(){
   //your code
});
```

and also why are you using two document.ready functions here............. ???

Comment: Answer: Because I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: you can add this code in one $.ready funcion . you don't need two